# AJAX won't load new page content without page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I executed an AJAX request to load content into my page. Here's the function I created for this request:

```
    function displayForums() {

        var session = "<?php echo $_SESSION['id'] ?>";

        $.ajax({
            url: 'includes/threads/display_forums.php',
            data: 'POST',
            data: {session: session},
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("display successful");
                $(data).appendTo("#forums-container");  
            }
        });
    }
```

Then, I call this function I just declared (displayForums()) when the document loads:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
displayForums();
});
```

Finally, I have an AJAX call that submits user input from a form into a database.

```
    $("#start-thread-form").on("submit", function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var forum_title = $("#start-thread-form input").val();
        var forum_message = $("#start-thread-form textarea").val();
        var id = "<?php echo $_SESSION['id'] ?>";

        $.ajax({
            url: 'includes/threads/insert_forums.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {forum_title: forum_title, forum_message: forum_message, id: id},
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $(".success-msg").append("Thread created successfully" + "<br>").show();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(".success-msg").hide();
                    $(".success-msg").text('');
                }, 2000);
                $('input[type="text"],textarea').val('');
                displayForums();
            }, 
            error: function(requestObject, error, errorThrown) {
                console.log(error);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
```

The problem is that when the AJAX call that inserts data into the database completes, the original AJAX call doesn't load the new data into the page unless I refresh the page. I tried placing the `displayForums()` function inside of the success function, but it didn't work. How can I adjust the AJAX calls to load the newly inserted data without refreshing the page?

Comment: AJAX is Asynchronous, so you have to put an AJAX call within another if you want to run a second one based on the first.

Comment: Given I understood your question correctly, you will need to create a new Ajax request by calling the first snippet again.

Comment: @Javan How would I call the first snippet again?

Comment: @CarsonD wrap the first ajax request in a function. Call the function on page load, which gets the first range of forums. After the click, assuming clicking something triggers the second ajax request (you haven't demonstrated this so I'm assuming), you call the function in the success callback of your second ajax request.

Comment: @Cue I'm putting the function of the first ajax call into the success function of the second ajax call, but still no new data. Do you want me to edit my post to show the code I just created?

Comment: First i suggest you to use another frame work for such project like Vue or React as it will be easir to manage data change ! , as 
you need to make the calls a Promises , so you can use then or better use Axios as its return promise by default 
// example axios for first query 
```
const GetForm = function(){
return axios.post('url',{a:'xcc',b:'xxx'}).then((data)=>{
// do you html change
})
}
```
then you can use it after any call example first for second query 
```
axios.post('InsertData',{'a':ss,'v','ssss'}).then(()=>{
GetForm
},err=>{
})
```
also can use same logic for Ajax

Comment: @CarsonD it would be useful to demonstrate, with updates to the original question, so we can better understand what you are trying first in order to assist you.

Comment: @JehadAhmadJaghoub Given the state of current affairs I really don't think suggesting an extensive framework like Vue or React is really contributing any lessons to learn, particularly when it doesn't relate to the question at hand. What the OP is trying to achieve can be done with or without a progressive framework. Opinions do not translate to solutions.

Comment: @Cue I updated the question. Let me know if there's still confusion.

Comment: @CarsonD Thanks a lot. Could you demonstrate your attempt in placing the call to `displayForums()` in your success callback? I know you mention it but it would be beneficial for us to see how you're implementing it.

Comment: @Cue Ok I just added where I placed it within the success callback, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run your JavaScript when the submit event of a form fires.

The default behaviour of a form submission is to make an HTTP request to the `action` and load the response **as a new page**.

If you don't want the form to submit, then you have to stop it.

```
$("#start-thread-form").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: I actually included that in the code above what I provided and just added it in. It seems to be working now that I formatted it in that way. Thanks. But now there's a new problem: the comments that were already loaded in from the first function are being repeated because I'm just copying the same function with the same information.

Comment: @CarsonD — Then you probably want to delete the existing ones before you append new ones.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(displayForums());
```

this is WRONG, it should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() { displayForums() });
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't fix the problem. But good to know.